# xmr-stak-amd and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xmr-stak-amd

I'm only able to make **xmr-stak-amd** working with **AMDGPU-PRO** proprietary driver, so I must remain on Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there a way to make **xmr-stak-amd** working with the **amdgpu** opensource driver? I mean the default driver in Ubuntu 17.04 or 17.10.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, no way to make **xmr-stak** (*xmr-stak-amd is legacy*) with the open-source AMD Linux driver.

Apart from that, the latest xmr-stak works like a charm with new **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** version and the [AMD Linux proprietary driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-570).